# GeoServer installed in external server - error to access to shapefile

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to publish a web map using GeoServer. In my PC everything works fine. I have the GeoServer installed and through http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ I access my data.

However I require to publish my web maps, so the Geoserver was installed in an external server. I have access from my computer using credentials. Inside this GeoServer I import my data (shapefiles). However when I try to see the data using OpenLayers this happens:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: you seem to be trying to access a machine called geonode - are you sure that is the name of the machine running geoserver? We really need to see the full URL you are making requests at

Comment: I have no knowledge so I do not know the name of the machine running geoserver. Geonode is from geoserver.

Comment: You can't connect to the remote machine if you don't know it's name. Geonode is a completely different program